# How can I calculate total values of table column after filtering in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good Day! I have a simple table with filter functionality in react. The table contains only car `name` and `price` with dropdown select for filtering cars with their name. I need to display the total price of filtered cars. here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-hooks-vetmx4?file=/src/App.js) .

What I tried was defining a function like this

```
const updateSubTotal = () => {
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        let subTotal = Array.from(table.rows)
          .slice(1)
          .reduce((total, row) => {
            return total + parseFloat(row.cells[1].innerHTML);
          }, 0);
        setTot(subTotal);
      };
```

Unfortunately, this function returns invalid value. Here is the whole code

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const data = [
  {
    name: "Saab",
    price: 100
  },
  {
    name: "Mercedes",
    price: 50
  },
  {
    name: "Audi",
    price: 10
  }
];
export default function App() {
  const [tot, setTot] = useState();

  const updateSubTotal = () => {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    let subTotal = Array.from(table.rows)
      .slice(1)
      .reduce((total, row) => {
        return total + parseFloat(row.cells[1].innerHTML);
      }, 0);
    setTot(subTotal);
  };
  //CALCULATE sum of prices
  const totalPrice = data.map((item) => item.price).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const DisplayData = data
    ?.filter((row) => row?.name?.match(new RegExp(searchValue, "i")))
    .map((cars) => {
      return (
        <tr key={cars.name}>
          <td>{cars?.name}</td>
          <td>{cars?.price}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
      <select
        name="cars"
        id="cars"
        value={searchValue}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSearchValue(e.target.value);
          updateSubTotal();
        }}
      >
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
      <table className="tables" id="myTable">
        <thead className="sticky-header overflow-hidden z-50">
          <tr>
            <th className="">Car Name</th>
            <th className="">Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{DisplayData}</tbody>
      </table>
      <div>Total Price without filter: {totalPrice}</div>
      <div>Total Price after filter: {tot}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you mean something like so - [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-knuth-t7hzbv?file=/src/App.js) ?

Comment: @KcH I appreciate your answer but it doesn't fix my problem. You only tried to return the single selected  car price. How about two of the same car with the same name but different price being filtered? it doesn't work

Comment: oh my bad,,,, I thought the select filters out ... but its confusing to me on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Let me explain again, assume you have two cars named with `Saab` with different `price` in the table. so when you filter a car with name `Saab`, you will get two rows of same car with different price. In this case how can i calculate the price of these prices? here is the updated code:  https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-hooks-vetmx4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Note that `row.cells[1].innerHTML` should almost certainly be using `.textContent` instead, and *even that* is a complete anti-pattern. You should really be deriving *both* the table *and* the total from the same array in state.

Comment: @TeshieEthiopia I hope the answer I posted is what you are looking for as per above comment  .... sorry if I misunderstood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using useState hook for the variables and grouping them at the beginning of your component (filteredCars list, filteredTotal)

```
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState(dropdownItems[0]);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState(filterData(searchValue));
  const [filteredTotal, setFilteredTotal] = useState(
    calculateTotal(filteredData)
  );
```

total value doesnt change, so its okay to leave it as a constant

```
  const total = calculateTotal(data);
```

then you trigger useEffect hook when those states change,
in your example everything depends on the dropdown selection, so filtering and summing should be done when selection changes

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredData(filterData(searchValue));
    setFilteredTotal(calculateTotal(filteredData));
  }, [searchValue, filteredData]);
```

Bonus tip :
Make dropdown items dynamic, create them by spreading names from data array

```
const dropdownItems = [notSelectedLabel, ...data.map((row) => row.name)];
```

You can take a look at the [codepen here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-brahmagupta-md642t?file=/src/App.js:264-338)

Comment: You are a helping hand! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- You can pass the value to handler and filter, then calculate sum using reduce method.
- I have added `id` for unique `keys` amongst list which is crucial when the list is not static.

[image: Edit sleepy-knuth-t7hzbv]